# Unable to load google in iframe in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

My iframe works fine with my internal pages however it fails when I set the source url to Google.

Here is my code, i'm using version 2 (latest)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".various").fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });
    });
</script>
<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=android" class="various fancybox.iframe">Open iframe</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a fancybox issue. Google doesn't like to be contained within iframes anymore due to changes in their adSense program policies.

*[AdSense code may not be altered, nor may the standard behavior, targeting or delivery of ads be manipulated in any way that is not explicitly permitted by Google. This includes but is not limited to the following: clicking Google ads may not result in a new browser window being launched, nor may Google ads be placed in an IFRAME.](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_medium=link&gsessionid=EfZI_Y4x1hhflIPanUpi1whttps%3a%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fadsense%2Fsupport%2Fbin%2Fanswer.py%3Fanswer%3D48182%3Futm_source%3Daso&utm_campaign=ww-ww-et-asblog_2011-06-10&answer=48182)*.