# FancyBox returning "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox to display inline content (a div with an image linked to a new page). The div and image display fine in the modal, but when the image is clicked to go to the new page, I get "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." error.

The FancyBox javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox().hover(function() {
            $(this).click();
        });
        $("#fancybox-outer").fancybox().mouseleave( function() {
               $("#fancybox-overlay").click();
         });
    });
</script>
```

And applies to the following clip of HTML:

```
<li class="fancybox-outer">
    <a id="inline" href="#hover-image_0" class="fancybox">
        <img src="http://website.com/file/id:63" style="margin-top: 32px" />
    </a>
    <p><a href="http://website.com/template/view/18">1G2A</a></p>
    <div style="display: none;"><div id="hover-image_0"><a href="http://website.com/template/view/18"><img src="http://website.com/file/id:64/ext:.png" class="img" /></a></div></div>
</li>

<li class="fancybox-outer">
    <a id="inline" href="#hover-image_1" class="fancybox">
        <img src="http://website.com/file/id:60" style="margin-top: 32px" />
    </a>
    <p><a href="http://website.com/template/view/17">17</a></p>
    <div style="display: none;"><div id="hover-image_1"><a href="http://website.com/template/view/17"><img src="http://website.com/file/id:61/ext:.png" class="img" /></a></div></div>
</li>
```

Does anyone see what might be causing the issue or what I need to correct?

Thanks!

**Update: 1/19/2012** - I performed the same test on my server as the first answer (http://estorkdelivery.com/example/example.html) and found that I got the same response back. So it seems it's something with my server.

I still need help with this issue. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

**Update: 1/28/2012** - I've been working to find a solution for this problem, but I've run out of time and have gone with a completely different solution. I'm keeping this problem open in case anyone else runs across the same error or ultimately finds a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your approach has many issues:

**First** bear un mind that fancybox gets its content from the `href` attribute of any selector bound to it so the link

```
<a class="fancybox" href="{target}" ...
```

should be bound to fancybox via the following script in order to work

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

Pretty obvious but in your approach, the link inside the opened fancybox (*which targets to yahoo for instance*) is not bound to fancybox itself; it will try to fire Fancybox for sure again but with no indication of what the content should be this time, hence the error "*The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later*." in other words, the link (inside the inline content) `<a href="http://yahoo.com" ...` is not bound to fancybox.

The only way that links inside fancybox can work and load content dynamically (without being bound to fancybox) is when the current content is an external `html` document and fancybox `type` was set to `iframe` (not your case)

**Second**, you opened an image so fancybox set the `type` to `image` by default, but then you are pretending to load a different type of content on the same box (yahoo for instance), which would require to set `type` to `iframe` and other options like `width` and `height`.

**Third**, since you are using inline content, please be aware of an existing bug in v1.3.x and its workaround to avoid further issues, [you can learn more here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/fab7b6d81a173b33/)

**Last**, I am not just lecturing here, it's more like the explanation of what is going on with your issue .... but the good news is that you just need to add some more lines of code to make it work the way you want:

1: you need to create a fancybox script for each type of content you want to open the second time (additionally to your existing one), so in your example you want to click the image inside fancybox and that should open yahoo ... then create this script

```
$('.fancyframe').fancybox({
 'type':'iframe',
 'width': 600, //or whatever you want
 'height': 300
});
```

2: within your hidden inline content set that class to the link, so this code:

```
<div style="display: none;">
 <div id="hover-image_0">
  <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="1_b.jpg" class="img" /></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

now should look like

```
<div style="display: none;">
 <div id="hover-image_0">
  <a class="fancyframe" href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="1_b.jpg" class="img" /></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Do the same for each hidden inline content. If you want to open another type of content in fancybox, just create a script accordingly. The rest of your code is OK (doesn't bother me to fire fancybox on hover)

**SIDE NOTES**: sites like google, yahoo, jquery and some others won't open in fancybox. Also make sure you have the proper `DOCTYPE` for fancybox to work properly (your sample page doesn't have any). See [Unable to load google in iframe in fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803053/unable-to-load-google-in-iframe-in-fancybox/8808761#8808761) for explanation.

Comment: WOW! ``Also make sure you have the proper DOCTYPE for fancybox to work properly``

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured out what's causing this issue, at least for me.

The problem seems to occur when you've got a class on one of your elements that is the same as the popup class.

For instance:

```
<a class="popup" href="#">Open the popup</a>
```

And you have something in your popup with the same class name, for instance:

```
<div class="popup">some text</div>
```

You'll get the error. Try changing the div class to something like `popup-window` - that should fix your error

In your example page, it works for me if I don't click. When you click, what page are you supposed to be taken to? Do you want it to just go to the next image?

In my personal preference, I don't care for the activation on hover. It gets really confusing, especially when most people go to instinctually click on an image. But in your case it opens on hover, then they click instinctually, then you get the error.

Do you get this same error when you're just using the functionality as it normally applies?

If you want, try to give each image a gallery name instance like so: `rel="gallery"` and see what happens. You should get the next/prev arrows showing up and working like you would expect.

But honestly, I would get rid of the hover functionality altogether. Or at least get rid of the mouseout() That's probably the most bothersome part.

Just use this to call the fancybox actions:

`$("a[rel=gallery]").fancybox();`

That way you can get rid of all of those classes that are probably causing the issues.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the thought out response. I appreciate that. Using the example page I setup, I don't have any duplicate classes as you can see, where the behavior is still happening... Or maybe I'm misunderstanding your explanation. If you look at the code, you can see from the inline content that each image is supposed to link to a new page - in the example one goes to Google, the other goes to Yahoo. Unfortunately, I have to keep the on hover and mouse out functions per what was requested of me.

Comment: well, the only thing I would say is that I would try to get it back to the most default set up you can and work your way backward.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue as well.

As it turns out, the href url is EXTRA case sensitive.  (if that is possible)

Regardless double, triple check your href urls to insure that you have the case exactly correct.

Answer (score 1):

my solution was:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        $(".fancybox").click(function() {
            $.fancybox({
                'padding'       : 0,
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                'titleShow'     : false,
                'showCloseButton': true,
                'titlePosition' : 'inside',
                'transitionOut' : 'none',
                'title'         : '',
                'width'         : 640,
                'height'        : 385,
                'href'          : this.href,
                'type'          : 'iframe',
                'helpers'     : { 
                                'overlay' : {'closeClick': false}
                                }

            });

            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If some of the images are showing and others are not, even though the markup is identical, then check this:

1. Try to lowercase all the letters in the filename and in the html. Fancybox seems to be quite case sensitive.
2. Check if the image has all the permissions allowed. I noticed my pictures didn't work properly on mobile because on my computer, everybody's permission was set to "no permission". I changed this to "read only" and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I just re-created your test on my local machine and it works fine for me (I ran this from the demo folder of the FancyBox install) :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Fancybox Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox().hover(function () {
            $(this).click();
        });
        $("#fancybox-outer").fancybox().mouseleave(function () {
            $("#fancybox-overlay").click();
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
    <li class="fancybox-outer"><a id="inline" href="#hover-image_0" class="fancybox">
        <img src="1_s.jpg" style="margin-top: 32px" />
    </a>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Go to Yahoo</a></p>
        <div style="display: none;">
            <div id="hover-image_0">
                <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">
                    <img src="1_b.jpg" class="img" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="fancybox-outer"><a id="inline" href="#hover-image_1" class="fancybox">
        <img src="2_s.jpg" style="margin-top: 32px" />
    </a>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a></p>
        <div style="display: none;">
            <div id="hover-image_1">
                <a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <img src="2_b.jpg" class="img" /></a></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess there's something in the rest of the code affecting the FancyBox display... Here's the website link: http://estorkdelivery.com/template

Answer (score 0):

I having the same problem with Fancybox. You cannot have spaces or special character in `href` and `div id`. Use an URL slug if you are using page titles.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking out all the possibilities and ran into the EXTRA case sensitivity issue as @BrettBumeter mentioned.
In fact, it is "so much case sensitive", I had to revrite the URL (href) path to my images from *.jpg to *.JPG (or whatever your file type extension might be).
Altering this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply the fancybox class to your LI element, do it to your A element.

Answer (score 0):

I, after taking the above advice, changed ".png" to ".PNG" in the href. NOTE that the file names are a lower case extension but it only works with upper case extension in the href (rest of filename same)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's most likely because your server is case-sensitive (linux?) not related to Fancybox.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was giving **inappropriate path to image e.g;**

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="../dist/imgs/nature/n1.png">
<img src="../dist/imgs/nature/n1.png"></a>
```

While the images loaded well locally, It could not do online.
Correcting the path solved the problem.

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="imgs/nature/n1.png">
<img src="imgs/nature/n1.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make Fancybox work with dynamic content, you may check this.

I was using the following code:

```
<a class="video__overlay" data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?= $blog_url ?>"></a>
```

My issue was that I was generating `$blog_url` dynamically, looking at a specific text file line, so a `\n` was being added at the end of `$blog_url`, without me noticing this.

So, I used `trim()` and everything works as expected.