# fancybox and links

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, hyperlink, href

i've searched the forums for a solution, but i couldn't find anything :)
i have a fancybox with a div inside it. inside this div i have things such as images, text and an external link (  tag ) to a website (ex. yahoo)
what i would like is, when i click the link, yahoo will open up in a new tab/window ( target:_blank ) but all i get is "the requested content cannot be loaded. please try again later"

here's the code:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#content"></a>
<div id="content">
      <img.... />
      <p>......</p>
      <a href="www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">yahoo.com</a>
</div>
```

thanks a lot for helping me out :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913583/fancybox-returning-the-requested-content-cannot-be-loaded-please-try-again-lat

Answer (score 2):

The browser takes `www.yahoo.com` as a relative url to your site, if you take a look to the address bar after clicking that link you'll see something like http://mysite.com/www.yahoo.com

You need to put the url in this format

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">yahoo.com</a>
```

Comment: Correct, if this link is inside your inline content (opened in fancybox), then yahoo will open in a new window/tab ... not inside fancybox!!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems:

The **href** attribute on your anchor is missing the **http://** protocol, it should be **http://www.yahoo.com**:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#content"></a>
<div id="content">
      <img.... />
      <p>......</p>
      <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">yahoo.com</a>
</div>
```

Also, some sites like Facebook, Yahoo or similar cannot be opened with fancybox, they're protected against iframes.

Comment: still not working :( but i'm not using iframes anywhere, though

Comment: Yes, but fancybox creates an iframe to display the webpage

Comment: @Skatox : that is not necessarily true. Fancybox will create an iframe only if you set that option, otherwise it will treat it as inline content.