# The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later. Fancybox

Tags: fancybox, inline

I'm using fancybox, which I've used hundreds of times before and I'm getting a "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." error in the modal box.  I'm expecting to see "Fancybox!! Yay!" Instead.

Code below.  Any ideas?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function init(){
        $("#upload-new").fancybox({type:'inline'});
    }
</script>

<p><a id="upload-new" href="#image-uploader">Upload new screenshot</a></p>

<div class="hidden">
    <div class="image-uploader">
        Fancybox!! Yay!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [FancyBox returning "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." with link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913583/fancybox-returning-the-requested-content-cannot-be-loaded-please-try-again-lat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
href="#image-uploader"
```

means that you are targeting an element with `id="image-uploader"` but you have :

```
<div class="image-uploader">
```

.... I guess it should be :

```
<div id="image-uploader">
```