# Why fancybox doesnt work online

Tags: fancybox

I am using the fancybox plugin for gallery on my website. Everything works fine on my localhost, but when I upload my website, and try to open an image in gallery there is a message: Requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later..
[This happens when i try to open an imgage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SAQB.png)

Does enyone know what is the problem?

Comment: You please add your code and check that what type of source you are trying to load.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913583/fancybox-returning-the-requested-content-cannot-be-loaded-please-try-again-lat

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are not using relative links eg. `<img src="/images/image.png">` vs `<img src="localhost/images/image.png">` best guess without seeing a code example.