# Can't load YouTube video in Fancybox - blank page

Tags: jquery, video, iframe, youtube, fancybox

Folks,

I'm trying to open a youtube video in fancybox using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
        jQuery("a.video").fancybox({            
                'hideOnContentClick'    : false,
                'width'         : '50%',
                'height'        : '50%',
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'          : 'iframe'
        });
    });
// ]]></script>
```

The fancybox iframe gets called by:

```
<a class="video" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9szn1QQfas"><img title="sometitle" src="http://pathToImage.png" alt="" width="140" height="103" /></a>
```

The fancybox pops up just fine. However, when a YouTube video is called, a white blank iframe is displayed.

When replacing the YT URL with http://www.amazon.com for example, the Amazon page gets loaded just fine. When using www.youtube.com (YT index page) or www.google.com, again a blank iframe is loaded.

I've been searching via google and stackoverflow for hours but couldn't find a solution that worked.

Help very much appreciated.

---

EDIT 02/01/2012: Sudhir, tanhuong, JFK, thanks for posting your answers. Much appreciated.

I used JFKs solution which worked great. Sorry, as a newbie here on SO I can't rate your answers. Otherwise I sure had.

Comment: you don't need to rate the answers, just mark which is the correct one for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sudhir's code is close but won't work; the right code to use for this scenario is:

```
$(".video").click(function() {
 $.fancybox({
  'hideOnContentClick': false,
  'autoScale': false,
  'transitionIn': 'none',
  'transitionOut': 'none',
  'title': this.title, // optional
  'width': 680, // or your size
  'height': 495,
  'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
  'type': 'swf',
  'swf': {
    'wmode': 'transparent',
    'allowfullscreen': 'true'
  }
 }); // fancybox
 return false;
}); // click
```

On the other hand, if you want to open external websites, the right `type` is `iframe`, however bear in mind that you won't be able to open `google` or `yahoo` and some other specific sites inside of fancybox (they won't like to be contained in iframes due to some ads policies, [check this for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808761/1055987) )... you may open your own website or external web pages though.

Answer (score 4):

Recently youtube embed code changed and it looks something like this: 
http://youtu.be/zH5bJSG0DZk. 
The way fancybox was working before looked something like this:

```
'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=","i"), 'v/')
```

Now, that is not really working with the new embed URL. After spending a few hours looking for a solution, I found it here:
http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/e8f81f420eed7c3c/f12af70aded87c2a

Basically, it switches the fancybox call to this:

```
 $.fancybox({
                    'padding' : 0,
                    'type' : 'iframe',
                    'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp('youtu.be', 'i'), 'www.youtube.com/embed').replace(new RegExp('watch\\?v=([a-z0-9\_\-]+)(&|\\?)?(.*)', 'i'), 'embed/$1?version=3&$3')
 });
```

I tested it with current embed code and old embed code and it seems to be working with both.

Comment: Thank you. This link was so helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fancybox/6PgfQg7tfDw  I finally got my Fancybox to play a Youtube video in IE9 without Flash installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("a.video").fancybox({
            'titleShow'     : false,
            'hideOnContentClick'    : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'      : 'swf',
            'swf'       : {'wmode':'transparent','allowfullscreen':'true'}
        });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sudhir, tanhuong, JFK, thanks for posting your answers. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

my solution:
add **'type' : 'iframe'** when you call fancybox() function.
Like this:
$("a#iframe-landing").fancybox({
                    'type' : 'iframe'
                });

and it works.
Hope it helps.