# Search Engines & iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I have a very basic html, supposingly

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

When I render the page with Google/Yahoo as a source address **there is no display**. This is what I see in firebug

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com">
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body></body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

If I am doing something wrong please correct else please provide any authentic documentation **if search englines have blocked iframes**. Would really appreciate.

p.s You can try the above example on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe) too.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803053/unable-to-load-google-in-iframe-in-fancybox

Comment: @AndrewBriggs: a good read, thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bypass it in browsers , they will simply refuse to display websites in `iframe` that send a
[X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) header with `DENY or SAMEORIGIN` . It doesn't even come down to javascript.
For more read on [ClickJacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) and [X-Frame-Options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking#X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can easily find out if your site is displayed inside a frameset/IFrame or if it is stands alone:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if(self!=top){/*I am framed*/}</script>
```

Probably Google has this code in one of its scripts, and when it finds out that its site is inside a foreign frame, it deletes its content.

With the same simple trick a html page can break out of every frame:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(self!=top){
      top.location.replace(self.location.href);
   }
</script>
```

If you want to try out this break-free-trick, replace in your code www.google.com with the url of my site: wissen.schoelnast.at (it is in German)

Answer (score 0):

what google says about iframe, read [Here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81766)

refer to **Avoid iFrames - or link to their content separately...**