# fancybox iframe Works / does not work with me

Tags: iframe, fancybox

Fancybox iframe is not working with me.. 
Can you please have a look and help.
It works for the "google map" link
but it does not work for the "list" link

http://thevillaproject.com/apex/f?p=150:2:0:::::

Comment: `list` links to `http://maps.google.com/` only. Are you sure this is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not that fancybox iframe doesn't work but the type of content. You cannot display any Google pages inside iframes so this URL `http://maps.google.com/maps` won't - work. [Check why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808761/1055987).

However, you could add the trial `?output=embed` to the link and it will work

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?output=embed" class="framefancybox"><p>list</p></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually my mean concern was to open APEX (Oracle Application Express) page on Fancybox. The solution ,as you implied,  in Security Attribute setting we allow of deny iframes.