# Fancybox opening hyperlinks in same popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I am using the fancybox iframe (as can be seen here in the iframe demo)
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/

Here is the code i am using

```
 <p><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="items/item1.html"><span>Item 1</span></a>
```

I then have item1.html that has the following code:

```
<h3>Item 1</h3>
Blah blah blah text here
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" width="160" height="25" border="0" alt="Google logo" /></a>
```

The fancybox pop up window works and pops up after clicking the items 1 link, however, once the fancybox is open and i can see the blahblah text and also the google logo, when i click the logo - the www.google.com should load but it doesn't.  What am i doing wrong?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open goolge inside fancybox or in any other lightbox, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808761/1055987 for more.

Change it to any other URL, preferably one of your own.

Comment: Actually I just gave google as an example, its a different external website (LinkedIn).

Comment: Most of the big players (google, facebook, linkedin, yahoo, etc.) don't like to be contained within iframes. Try with another one ... yours for example.

Comment: It's mostly due to the SAMEORIGIN policy (The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.)

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that it is opening inside the fancybox? If so you can add a target="_blank" to the href and it will open in a new tab/window. The html in your document that is iFramed will look like this:

```
<h3>Item 1</h3>
  Blah blah blah text here
  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">
     <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" width="160" height="25" border="0" alt="Google logo" />
  </a>
```

Comment: No the problem is that I WANT it to open in the fancybox, but it isn't! When I click the google image link, nothing happens. The page looks like it reloads but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Web sites with sensitive user data often block framing by adding an HTTP header callled [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) to their pages to prevent [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) attacks. There isn't much that you can do about it, other than proxying the page through your own server.